# What is difference between connecting to a Wifi hotspot using Android's "Settings" menu and doing it programatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi

When I create a Wifi hotspot through the "Settings" menu in Android, I am able to connect to my Wifi hotspot however, when I do so programatically (using `WifiManager`'s `addNetwork()`, `disconnect()`, `enableNetwork()` and `reconnect()`)  I am not able to do it. What's the difference between both the methods of creating and connecting to Wifi? Is there any way to overcome that difference through a program?

Answer (score 1):

I explain it: Cretae wifi Hotspot using settings is not actually you create hotspot you just on your default hotspot which is already created by android system.
Here you just on/off for other wifi.

and

Create you it by programmatically means you have create a (hotspotpoint)point for other users so when you create it by programatically its not start default point, its your own point. then it to on/off for other wifi.

What's the difference between both the methods of creating and connecting to Wifi ans:
i will give you example suppose bought tv is creating a point. but without its power switch you can not see moive other other channels same like without (connecting) wifi on other and you cant connect to other wifi hotspot. i hope you understand..

thats it...

Comment: Hey thanks Jay. Is there any source/refernce for this? Also, is there any way I can overcome that difference in a program?

Comment: yes there are check android developer site for wifi hotspot and wifi. and mark as ans if it is use ful.

Comment: Checked. I couldn't really find anything similar to what you are mentioning. Could you please provide a link?

Comment: Also Read about WifiManager.

Comment: I have used WifiManager. (If you want to see my same code go to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075343/how-do-i-connect-to-multiple-wifi-networks-one-after-the-another-programatically).

I meant reference for your statement: " Create wifi Hotspot using settings is not actually you create hotspot you just on your default hotspot which is already created by android system." I couldn't find any reference supporting this statement.